# Running test with testcontainers as part of a Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, maven, testcontainers

My dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11-slim
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN mvn clean install
```

That means that part of the build is the execution of the unit tests. Some of the unit tests use a testcontainer. Running `mvn clean install` on my local machine works fine, but running `docker build . -t my-app` doesn't because the testcontainers won't start.

```
(...)
15:54:38.793 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Pinging docker daemon...
15:54:38.794 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.transport.okhttp.OkHttpDockerCmdExecFactory$1@355cb260
15:54:39.301 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Pinging docker daemon...
15:54:39.301 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.transport.okhttp.OkHttpDockerCmdExecFactory$1@1c1a1359
15:54:39.469 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy - ping failed with configuration Environment variables, system properties and defaults. Resolved dockerHost=unix:///var/run/docker.sock due to org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for result with exception
org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for result with exception
(...)
```

I've seen examples of running `docker run` with working testcontainers, but how do I make my `docker build` work?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you run your build inside a docker container and running inside that container Testcontainers ? Which means Docker in Docker ...? Why running your build inside a container any special requirements?

Comment: I use a multi stage docker file to build te project. Building the project inside a container, to be able to make a clean build in any environment. That is why.

Controlling the host's Docker engine from inside the maven/java-container is fine. Using Docker in Docker (having a separate Docker engine inside the maven/java-container) is also fine. As long as I get it to work...

Comment: You need to start an additional container before building and refer to it via environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842771/19541281

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: I believe this is simply not possible.

[`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) allows you to mount the Docker socket (and thus access the host's Docker daemon) with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.

[`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) doesn't support such an argument.

My workaround will be to modify my Dockerfile to
`RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and run the unit tests separately.

Answer (score 0):

In the docker file, you need to have docker installed to run TestContainer.
I have learned this from one of the existing projects in my workplace. hopefully, it can give you some hints to solve your problem.

```
RUN curl -fsSL get.docker.com | sh

RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

In the docker-compose file,

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - /mnt/cachedata/.m2:/root/.m2
  - .:/app
```